# Appium in windows

Tags: android-activity, selenium-webdriver, automation, windows-8.1, appium

I am new in appium automation. When I open appium and selecting .apk file the packagename and acticity is showing as empty. Please help me to solve the issue .Running appium in windows. Appium version 1.3.4.1

Comment: issue image link  http://imgur.com/NPoprrs

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, the **Appactivity** and **apppackages** aren't populated until you actually launch a session with that .apk (via inspector is the easiest way). In addition, if you just want to know those values of the app, you can check it via monitor.bat, filtering "com" in the console log, and looking for the appropriate activites

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your apk file is incorrect? You may try to decompile it, using **apktool**.

Usage:
`apktool.bat d path-to-apk-file.apk`

Apktool will generate folder, open it and go to Manifest file. Look for tag named "activity" and "package". Example manifest:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.my.package.name">
    <application>
        <activity android:name="com.example.activity">
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>`

Answer (score 0):

Please check "aapt.exe" is available under SDK 'tools' or 'platform-tools' section, Appium uses "aapt dump badging apkpath" to get APK information.
If yes then set path variable.
You can also receive all information about.Apk using above command.
I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Please use 
**aapt.exe dump badging**  (In Windows)
**./aapt dump badging**  (In Linux/MAC)

for getting relevant package and activity from the app.

Or better use "app" property in DesiredCapability to directly specify app's URL or absolute path.

Comment: You can even check with the developer to get these details. They will provide readily. These details are essential if you don't have the *.apk file.

Answer (score 0):

Hello you must select the button of Application Path in first.
And make empty the fields of the application path.
And put again the path to your apk file.
Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution for Android**

Good way to get `AppPackage` and `AppActivity` is to use the `apkInfo` App.

To do so

- Download the `apkinfo` app from playstore on the same mobile on which you have installed the app under test.
- Open `apk info` app and select the app under test from the list ( You can also search for the app).
- Once you got the app, long press on the app and select "detailed information" which shows the app package and all the Activities.

I have listed all of these steps with screenshots [here on my blog:](http://awesomeautomation.blogspot.in/)

Answer (score 0):

@prasanth, Please upgrade the version of your appium because newer version have this feature. try appium 1.3.7.2 and onwards. It will work.